# Similar `return` values when mutating objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

I never had though deep about `return` until I was playing with some codes and encountered this nice catch.
`var x = [{a:2}, {a:4}, {b:4}]`
When I mutate some values inside the objects, I found same response for 3 different kinds of `return`. I know why it does so but not to the very low machine level. Can anyone explain why these 3 `return` return the same thing and when I should be careful of this?

```js
x.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.a === 2) {
    elem.a = 4
  }
})

x.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.a === 2) {
    elem.a = 4
    return elem
  }
})

x.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.a === 2) {
    elem.a = 4
  }
  return elem
})

  => x is always [{a: 4}, {a: 4}, {b: 4}]
```

I have a feeling it's due to `forEach` but not sure. Thanks for reading :D

Comment: Yes, the reason is that `forEach` ignores what value you return. No, the different snippets do not return the same thing.

Comment: I might be wrong here but, this sounds like the forEach is mutating the elements and this doesn't have to do with return.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, all the three snippets returns the same value for the array x as I mentioned.

Comment: @Hodrobond You're right. Here, I just mutate the values and as the object pointers all refer to same memory location, the values come out mutated over the original. I'm just scared this (i'd say bad coding style) might cause some serious problems to me later xD

Comment: @Jamie I meant "the functions in the different snippets don't `return` the same thing" of course. Yes, you are getting the same results in the `x` array despite that. And yes, I'd recommend to never use `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. The first returns nothing at the end of operation. It just changes values and returns void. The second returns the changed array item and the third also returns the last changed value but for 'else' case as well.